# Hazelcast - Switching delay when using sticky session

Tags: session, hazelcast, jetty-9

I have setup session replication using hazelcast and jetty 9 instances. The setup works perfectly when I configure the load balancer to route the request without using sticky session. But when I activated sticky session, there is a 30 seconds delay before the request is transferred to another member of the cluster. Is there anything that I have missed? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using deferredWrite=true and your http request lifecycle is around 30 seconds?

Comment: when you say sticky configuration, you mean sticky configuration in web.xml or load balancer?

Comment: i enabled the sticky configuration via console of my load balancer.

Comment: can you also set sticky config in web.xml for hazelcast-wm module? How long is your each http request processing period? Are you doing any having processing during http request/response cycle?